# Microsoft Graph missing attribute

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph API to query for user data. I've succesfully obtained access token and simple queries such as `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me` work just fine.

The problem is that the query's response is missing attributes such as `fax` which is very important for me. Using the old `https://graph.windows.net` endpoint returns `facsimileTelephoneNumber` attribute (which is the same) but I cannot use this older endpoint.

I've tried following https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2151 answer (3rd message) but I can't get the extensions working and I don't even know if it would have any help to this problem.

So is it possible to access `fax` attribute using the newer Microsoft Graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitHub answer you linked to was in regards to a personal contact, not users in the Active Directory. So to save you some frustration, that isn't the way forward :).

When you query for `/me`, you're getting the user's entry from Active Directory. This is a [user resource](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/user) in Graph. From the reference, the user resource has no property that exposes a fax number. Just to make sure the docs weren't incorrect, I checked the metadata exposed by the service (`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata`), and there is no fax field on a user.

There's a request on UserVoice (https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/18166054-microsoft-graph-api-user-fax-number) already to add this, you may want to go vote that up.

Answer (score -1):

The Graph doesn't expose all of these fields.

try using https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters

I think in your case this will work
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=fax

If you want more properties of the user resource you can add them as comma separated values after the select query parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, empty response.